# Next.js + Strapi blog: content not updated

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi

I have a Next.js app in production. My content is managed via Strapi. I fetch all the content with `getStaticProps` function on each page (2 pages actually, small blog).

However, when I create new content or update an existing one, my Next.js app doesn't fetch the new or updated content.

Maybe due to the fetching at build time? If yes, can I have the possibility to fetch the content on client side and have the benefit of SEO?

Any idea?

Many thanks! :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considered setting up a `revalidate` policy for [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://vercel.com/docs/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration) to freshen-up stale content.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration

```
// This function gets called at build time on server-side.
// It may be called again, on a serverless function, if
// revalidation is enabled and a new request comes in
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every 10 seconds
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  }
}
```

If that doesn't fit your update policy, you'll have to move to [server-side rendering and fetch data on each request](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering).

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works really great on my side!

But I have a question, how it works actually? Is that trigger a build every 10s (in that case)? Or that rebuild only on demand? I mean, is that trigger the rebuild only when a user hit that page?

Thanks again!

Comment: From the request flow docs: > After the 60 second window, the next request will still show the cached (stale) page. Next.js triggers a regeneration of the page in the background.
> Once the page has been successfully generated, Next.js will invalidate the cache and show the updated product page. If the background regeneration fails, the old page remains unaltered.

Comment: Yes, I read it, but is there a rebuild every 60s or only when a user hit the page?

Comment: "the next request will still show the cached (stale) page". So no, no request, no regeneration trigger, no regeneration.